# Firebase Firestore, Update a field in a document with a function parameter or variable

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I create the function below to update a name in a collection.
The function takes the uid and the new name as parameters.
The behavior I am getting is, once called the value of firstName in the db is being replaced by an object with a key-value pair being `firstName` and the value of `newFirstName`.
i.e `firstName: {firstName: newFirstName}`. I also added a screenshot below to illustrate what I mean.

I'm sure where I am getting this wrong

Thanks for your help

```
export async function dbUpdateFirstName(uid, newFirstName){
  
  try{
    usersRef.doc(uid).update({
        "firstName" : newFirstName
    })
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    return err
  }

}
```

[firestore screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd6u7.png)

Comment: Try adding `await` before `usersRef.doc(uid)`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It await and it doesn't change anything. newFirstName is a string.

Comment: What type of value is `newFirstName`? From the screenshot it seems that `newFirstName` is an object with the property firstName within it. Can you print it with `console.log(typeof(newFirstName));` before saving it to firestore and share the results here?

Comment: When you hard type the value like this: `await docRef.update({"firstName": 'Test name'})`. Do you see the same results? Please also include how the `usersRef` variable is created.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance. I found the solution. I wasn't passing a string but an object instead from react hook form on submit method instead of the property firstName from the return object.

Comment: Hey there, gladly to hear I could help somehow. Since stackoverflow is a community of questions and answers I have posted my comments as an answer so that it has more visibility. If my answer worked out for you, please accept it so that it may help other members that may face the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshots I can see that `newFirstName` is an object and not a string and this is what caused your issue.

You can verify this behavior by printing `newFirstName` before the document is updated.

`console.log(newFirstname);`

And if this does not shed some light on, you can as well print the type of `newFirstName` with:

`console.log(typeof(newFirstName));`